# How can I maintain Django database entries after making migrations and pushing changes to Git?

Tags: python, sql, django, git, github

I have constructed essentially a blog in Django, where various users can input Articles to the blog I host on a remote server. However, if I change any of the model 'Article' field attributes (and therefore update migrations) and push them to Git with "git commit -m" and "git push -u origin master" I notice that any of the blog posts made prior to this commit vanish from the webpage.

I would like it to be, that when I make changes in the Python code that constitutes my Django project, pushing through these changes doesn't delete blog posts each time.

My Article model looks as follows:

```
class Article(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    #Body is the "body" of our entry - self explanatory. 
    body = models.TextField()
    #date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(
        get_user_model(),
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
    )
    entry_date_time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Whenever I update through Git though, all the old 'articles' published on my blog disappear. How can I either a) prevent that, or b) circumvent that?

I appreciate any and all help / solutions, thank you.

Comment: Could it be possible you are using SQLite AND your local dev db has been added to your repoositorie ? This is actually the only thing I can think of that would cause such a behaviour.

Comment: I am using sqlite3. I am not sure if the dev db has been added to the repository. How would I check / fix that issue?

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a sqlite database, you should add your db to `.gitignore` file or change the database location (out of git tracker)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I am using sqlite3. How would I add my db to .gitignore or change location (apologies as I am new to Django)?

Comment: use this [link](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/ignoring-files) for ignore db